# SVM with non-negative weights

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, libsvm, computer-vision

An SVM classifier can be obtained by solving the following,

$\arg\min \frac{1}{2}\|W\|_2^2 + C\sum_i \max(0, 1-y_i (W^T\mathbf{x}_i + b))$

where $W$ is the hyperplane (or weights), $b$ is the bias, $y_i$  is the label and $\mathbf{x}_i$ is the feature of an instance $i$.

For some reason I need to constaint all the elements in $W$ should be non-negative, i.e. $w_j \geq 0, \forall j$. Bias could take any values.

1. Is this reasonable?
2. If it is, are there any pakages (e.g. liblinear) I can use directly for this?
3. How can I optimize $W$ with non-negative constraints?

Answer (score 1):

Initially, I think the model is fine but I don't know any package can solve this model directly.

One method is that you may can try to write the dual form of this problem. I believe it will be a QP problem with extra nonnegative constrains.

Alternatively, you also can try to find some algorithms which updates $w_{i}$ separately so that you can slightly rewrite the iteration formulas with $w_i^* = max(w_i, 0)$.

Comment: I made a Python library can solve the nonnegative-SVM (https://github.com/statmlben/Variant-SVM).

Answer (score 0):

As @Ben Dai suggests, this looks like it will be a quadratic programming problem with inequality constraints.  There are various general quadratic programming packages available which may be used to solve the problem, such as the [quadprog](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/quadprog.html) routine in the MATLAB optimisation toolbox.  This is only such routine I have used, but there are many other [packages](http://www.numerical.rl.ac.uk/people/nimg/qp/qp.html) for this sort of problem.